# Request sent successfully but no response is coming back.

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, post

I am sending a post request using jquery Ajax to java Restful Webservice. Request is submitted successfully but no response is coming back.

Jquery Code

```
$.ajax({           
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Sampleprj/getData",
    data: "{\"result\": \"Hello\"}",
    crossDomain: true, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){    
    },
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){ 
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    }
});
```

Java Code :-

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/getData")
public @ResponseBody String getRequest(@RequestBody String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    return "{\"result\": \"Hello\"}";
}
```

Data coming from jquery is successfully printed to console but no data is returning back to jquery. It is going in error function and showing 200 OK status in firebug console without any response.

Comment: type some alert in all the method ,success , fail etc , and see if it is returning any error

Comment: I think you have to set content type

Comment: `no data is returning back to jquery.` -  based on what? Where are you able to log data from?

Comment: I have used alert in all method it is going in error section but not printing any error. Also set content-type but no luck.

Comment: Problem Resolved :)
I have add this part to server side.

Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");